Issues with content hub on Open Graph images or Twitter Images in SXA for SEO
Sitecore has OOTB feature for Open graph and Twitter tags. This work perfectly fine for images used from Media Library. However when the images are used from Content Hub, the source is not set correctly.
Is there any work around to solve this problem by still using the OOTB features instead of writing the custom code?
Any help or info is greatly appreciated.
Below is the snapshot of tag generated when Content hub image is used.

Below is the snapshot of tag generated when media library image is used, as expected.


Please add html code instead of screenshot for better SEO.

OOTB there is no such support for SXA component types inside Content Hub DAM. You are getting this issue since MediaManager.GetMediaUrl() reads the MediaItem to generate media url. Hence this need to be modified to address this issue.
You can create a extension method as below to read src attribute of image retreived from Content Hub, otherwise read from MediaItem.
public static class MediaExtension
{
   public static string GetImageUrl(this Field field, Item item, ID fieldId, bool includeServerUrl = true)
   {
      var imageUrl = string.Empty;
      if (field != null)
      {
         var imageField = (ImageField)field;
         if (imageField != null)
         {
            if (imageField.MediaItem == null)
            {
               XmlField imageDAMField = item?.Fields[fieldId];
               string src = imageDAMField.GetAttribute("src");
               return src;
            }
            else
            {
               var urlOptions = new MediaUrlBuilderOptions();
               urlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = includeServerUrl;
               return MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem, urlOptions);
            }
         }
      }
      return imageUrl;
    }
}

Thereafter inside OpenGraph Controller, above extension method can be called as below to retrieve image field url.
var imageField = item.Fields["OpenGraphImageUrl"];
if (imageField != null)
{
   imageSrc = imageField.GetImageUrl(item, imageField.ID, false);
}

You can find more details for the same here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/connect-for-ch/latest/connect-for-content-hub/troubleshooting-scch.html#sxa-fields-do-not-work-with-dam-functionality
Hope this helps!!!

This was really helpful. Thanks.... I got this custom implementation working..

@SyedAmanulla Glad to hear that..Can you please accept the answer as well so that it can be useful for other members in the community as well..Thank you!!!
